# How to fill lists of lists if there is missing some key and values?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of lists with "key and values" inside. But it miss one list key and value.
`[[a,1],[b,2][c,3] BLANK [e,5]]`
How to fill that gap between c and e if I have fixed keys that comes one after another by loop, actually it doesn't have to be a dictionary I just need fill data as key and Nan data to convert it to proper Dataframe with any code. More about list of lists data is here https://pastebin.com/dyRKFN7m

I've tried already to concat data but it miss empty key pair in dictionary.

```
python3
n = len(columns)
ndf = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame([df['data'][i:i+n].tolist()]) for i in range(0, len(df), n)], ignore_index=True)
```

This code also doesn't work

```py
d = dict()
last = None
for i, l in enumerate(string.letters_lowercase):
    if l not in d and last is None:
        last = i
    else:
        d.update(dict.from_keys(letters[last:i], 'missing')
        last = None
Expected result is in pastebin link upside
```

Comment: Are you looking for `[v, i+1 for i,v in enumerate(string.ascii_lowercase)]`? what does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: Your example in the question doesn't really match what you're planning to do on pastebin? Also, your list on pastebin has each "key" repeated twice, it won't work with dicts

Comment: Please can you review your variable names in pastbin. Things are messy, you don't respect case and you have a lot of mistakes (reciever >> receiver) which makes your data really difficult to read and use.

Comment: Sorry I will review that

Comment: @h4z3 It doesn't have to a dictionary, I just need to fill data so I can transer data to dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you this. I've reviewed your pastbin data since it seems to be full of typing mistakes

```py
fixed_keys = ['client_id', 'income', 'outcome', 'sender_bin', 'receiver_bin', 'sender_name', 'receiver_name', 'comment']

data = [["client_id", "1007896"], 
["income", "7896.3"], 
["outcome", "98933.2"], 
["sender_bin", "9999968999"], 
["receiver_bin", "136988966"], 
["sender_name", "Client1"], 
["receiver_bin", "Our Bank"], 
["comment", "Monthly Payment for goods"], 
["client_id", "1002587"], 
["income", "0"], 
["outcome", "6989"], 
["sender_bin", "9968996398"], 
["receiver_bin", "136988966"], 
["sender_name", "client3"], 
["receiver_bin", "Our Bank"], 
["comment", "Goods delivered"], 
["client_id", "1009635"], 
["income", "986.5"], 
["outcome","0"], 
["sender_bin", "136988966"], 
["sender_name", "Account manager Beatrice"], 
["receiver_bin", "Our Bank"], 
["comment", "income from cash collection"]]


for key in fixed_keys:
  isHere = False
  for pair in data:
    if key == pair[0]:
      isHere = True
  if(not(isHere)):
    data.append([key, "Nan"])
```

Comment: sorry, English is not my native language

Comment: Hi, I tried to run your example but it doesn't work properly. could you check it please?